# Grails - Spring Security - authentication error

Tags: authentication, grails, cookies, spring-security

I have a strange problem with an authentication of users in Grails using Spring Security plugin:

- When the user logs into his account, he sees credentials of completely different user (I print out the credentials)
- Sometimes the credentials switch to other user when user is already correctly authenticated.

This problem does occur neither on my development machine nor on a test serwer. 
The evironment where problem is present:

- Students in a school are testing the system on school's computers
- Each student registers as a new user
- School's computers has some security restrictions (that I don't know)
- All computers has one IP assigned (I don't know how internal network is configured yet)

Firstly, I thought it had something to do with cookie storage (j_session_id), but students could log in to Facebook or Gmail, etc. without any unexpected account switches.

It looks as if all cookies on all computers are being overriden when new user logs in - this was my guess but I can't confirm that all consequent users have the same - last logged user's credentials.

Sadly, I can't debug it at school's place, because it's far away.

How can I find out what is going on?

What might be the possible cause of the problem?

Why have users often different credentials when they are logging in?

Comment: This is a random shot in the dark, but could it be an issue with content being cached by the users' browsers?  If this is a possibility, you might take a look this plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/cache-headers